# Which mechanism will this reaction follow?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image] What could be a possible mechanism? Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in the first step, all the ethers are hydrolysed because they are easily cleaved in acidic medium which is provided here by $\ce{H_3O^+}$ and after hydrolysis, the gem-diols will be formed which will be immediately converted into ketone  by loss of $\ce{H_2O}$ molecules . Then, the rearrangement will be a **keto-enol tautomerism** which will yield ***Resorcinol***. After  that aqueous bromine solution will exhibit activated electrophilic aromatic substitution to yield **C)**. The mechanism is as follows,[image]